# Ranking basicity from a structure

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base

I just came across this question in my revision.

[image]

I selected (A) but the correct answer is (D).

Could someone explain where I am going wrong?

- I is least stable --> most reactive --> most basic
- Cl is more electronegative than F so III will have a stronger inductive stabilization effect -->  III is more stable than II --> III is less reactive than II --> III is less basic than II
- Hence, rank order: I, II, III

Comment: You might want to review the electronegativities of F and Cl.

Comment: From an instructive perspective, it would be nice to see an answer including the pKa all three compounds determined under shared conditions (for the the same solvent); especially for the comparison II vs. III, though.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: I had the electronegativity of F vs Cl the wrong way round.